# Create new session variable for dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, php

box which on-click appends a new text-box using javascript. now i want to capture the input and create a new php session variable of the input how do i do this?

This is my code:

```
<input onClick="myFunction();" type="checkbox"/>Demote to Child
<span id="DemoteContainer">// add textbox onclick here //</span>
<script>
//add textbox function
function myFunction()
{
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.innerHTML = '<input id="demo" name = "demo" type="textbox" />';
document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
}
</script>
<?
{
$_SESSION['temp']=$_POST['demo'];
}?>
```

This doesn't work how else should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this `session_start();` before you start using $_SESSION variable.

Comment: i have added that actually. this is just a small part of my huge code

Comment: Well, input from textbox doesn't appear in the $_POST var by some magic. You need either wrap your input in <form> tag and submit it, or use AJAX.

Comment: the form tag is also used. any help on how to use ajax? an example maybe?